# ICC - unclear comment from reviewer

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I'm new here and not a statistician, so I apologize in advance and I sure hope someone can help!

I'm working on a study where we have 10 locations $(5 \ intervention, 5 \ control)$. We have two measurements of activity for each participant $(n=  700)$ at each location. I've received the following comment from a reviewer: "Typically an intracluster correlation coefficient (ICC) is calculated to adjust for the correlation between participants at a single location"

I know how to calculate ICC using SPSS, but because there are different numbers of participants at each location, I'm a little confused... can anyone help?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: CV aims to be a repository of questions that are useful to others. With that in mind, could you edit your title to reflect the statistical question, rather than the circumstances in which it arose?

Comment: "I'm a little confused, can anyone help" is not a very specific question. Are you asking whether the usual computations for intraclass correlation are still valid in the case of unequal cluster sizes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you analyzing the data as a clustered randomized trial? Well I guess randomization doesn't really matter in this case. But have you addressed clustering in some way? If yes, ignore (2).
2. You need to address clustering in some way. I'm sure there are many ways to do this. The first that comes to mind would be a mixed-effects model with a random effect for location/cluster. (This is a commonly cited reference: [Methods for evaluating area-wide and organisation-based interventions in health and health care: a systematic review](http://www.hta.ac.uk/fullmono/mon305.pdf)) But depends on your study and field of research. I've seen location modeled as a fixed effect. This can be useful. More important is what the standard practice is in your field.
3. Usually clustering is addressed in the modeling stage. An actual ICC could be generated, but not sure how it would be useful. This may just be a limitation of my understanding generally.  (ICCs are often used in the sample size estimation stage. But sounds like you're way beyond that now.)